A Hölder norm of square root of a $C^2$ function
Background
I am reading a proof of the Calabi-Yau theorem from these notes. In page 15 he claims the following statement without proof (calling it elementary): Let $M$ be a compact manifold. There exists some $C$ that depends only on $M$ such that
$$||\sqrt{h}||_{1,0}\leq C(1+||h||_{1,1}),\qquad \forall h\in C^2(M), h\geq 0 .$$
The author says this follows from a one real variable analysis. I found this stack-exchange question showing the one-dimensional case if $h>\epsilon>0$ (bounding with the $C^2$ norm, though). The answerer claims it can be proven for $h\geq 0$ by approximations, which I am failing to see too.
In the Calabi-Yau proof, the author then goes on to use it with $||\sqrt[n-1]{h}_{1,0}||$ instead of $||\sqrt[2]{h}||_{1,0}$.
My Questions

How do you prove this in the one-dimensional case with $h\geq 0$ general?
Is the $C^{2,0}$ norm bounded by the $C^{1,1}$ norm? I doubt this is true...
How to conclude this for the multiple dimensional (compact) case?
What about the fact this result is used for a root that is not the square root?

My attempt
Following the guidance, assuming this is true for all $h\geq \epsilon>0$, take $h_\epsilon=h+\epsilon$, and then, clearly
$$ \sup{\sqrt{h_\epsilon}}\leq \sup\sqrt{h}+\sqrt \epsilon,$$
so $\sqrt{h_\epsilon}\xrightarrow{C^1}\sqrt{h}$. For the Lipschitz bound, I do:
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{h_\epsilon(x)}-\sqrt{h_\epsilon(y)}-(\sqrt{h(x)}-\sqrt{h(y)})| &= \left\vert\int_0^\epsilon\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}\left({\sqrt{h_\eta(x)}}-{\sqrt{h_\eta(y)}}\right)d\eta\right\vert \\
&\leq \frac12\int_0^{\epsilon} \left\vert\frac{1}{\sqrt{h_\eta(x)}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{h_\eta(y)}}\right\vert d\eta \\
&\leq C(1+||h||_{1,1})|x-y|\int_0^\epsilon\frac1{\sqrt{h_\eta(x)h_\eta(y)}}d\eta.
\end{align*}
This is almost good, except that the last integral is not integrable. In fact, writing this, I see that such an approach will not work when at a point $x$ such that $h(x)=0$, because then the LHS is independent of $x$.
I am quite disappointed someone writes such a statement that is impossible to verify in such a dismissing manner.

What if $M=[0,1]$ and $h(x) =x$? Then $\sqrt h$ is not Lipschitz, so the left-hand side is infinite and the right-hand side is finite. Maybe the condition $h\ge0$ is a typo and should have been $h>0$?

Seems that the manifold is without boundary. Then  $h(x)=0$ implies $h'(x)=0$, so $h$ behaves like $\frac12 h''(x)(y-x)^2$ for $y \approx x$, and $|\sqrt{ h(y)} -\sqrt{ h(x)}| \le c |h|_{C^{1,1}}$ near such $x$.

Clearly $h'(x)=$, but I fail to see how "behaves like" can be formulated appropriately. In particular, what does $h(y)=\frac12h''(x)(y-x)^2+o((y-x)^2)$ imply on the square root? I get that
$$|\sqrt{h(y)}-\sqrt{h(x)}|=\sqrt{h(y)}=\sqrt{\frac12 h''(x)}|y-x|+o(y-x)$$
but I cannot control the coefficient uniformly unless I know anything about $h^{(3)}$...

Just wanted to reinforce your statement: "I am quite disappointed someone writes such a statement that is impossible to verify in such a dismissing manner." Doing so is wholly unscientific and unprofessional. If an author has statements impossible to verify that write 'its trivially true' it brings all of their following and previous work into question.

Have you looked at the original paper to see how this is handled there?

When you say original paper, what do you mean? I couldn't find a reference in the paper I linked.

Yau's original paper.

I am wondering why integrating $\eta$ over $[0,\epsilon]$? A limit as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$ does not suffer from the integrability issue: Write
$$
|\sqrt{h(x)} - \sqrt{h(y)}
|
=
\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}|\sqrt{h_\epsilon(x)} - \sqrt{h_\epsilon(y)}|
$$
and thanks to the linked question Lipschitizianity of the square root of a positive $C^2$ function, for each fixed $\epsilon$ inequality $|\sqrt{h_\epsilon(x)} - \sqrt{h_\epsilon(y)}| \le |x-y| C(1+\|h\|_{1,1})$ holds.
One interpretation of the issue when integrating $\eta$ over $[0,\epsilon]$ is that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is $1/2$-Holder but not Lipschitz, so integration of a derivative of a function of the form $\sqrt{h(t)}$ with $h(t)=0$ for some $t$ yields integration issues. But sticking to $1/2$-Holder inequalities without integration is fine.
